# Where is the simpUser header taken from?

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket

According to documentation:

**The SecurityContextHolder is populated with the user within the `simpUser` header attribute for any inbound request.**

Once set on **CONNECT** request, the user (`simpUser`) will be stored in the `websocket` session and no more authentication will be required on further messages.

Where is the `simpUser` header taken from?